# In bluebird, execute multiple promise arrays concurrently

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I would like to do something like this:

```
given:
a = [a bunch of promises]
b = [another bunch of promises]
c = [more promises]

do:
return Bluebird.all(a, b, c).spread((resolved_a, resolved_b, resolved_c) => {
  // do stuff
})
```

This doesn't seems to work. Promise.all works fine when given multiple individual promises, or a single array of promises.

Thank you!

@Andy Gaskell,

Using the spread version, I'm not getting quite the behavior I want.
Given:

```
a = an array with three promises that resolve to 'a', 'b', and 'c'
b = like a but resolves 'd', 'e', 'f'
d = like a but resolves 'g', 'h', 'i'

return Bluebird.all(a, b, c,).spread((ra, rb, rc) => {
  console.log(ra) // 'a', 'b', 'c'
  console.log(rb) // 'd', 'e', 'f'
  console.log(rc) // 'g', 'h', 'i'
}
```

I want to keep the resolved promises separated in the .then(). Spreading or contracting the arrays flattened them and therefore combined the resolved promises into a single array.

Perhaps this is not possible?

@tincot

Your approach is almost there, the resolved promises are structured perfectly, but do not seem (I think, haven't totally convinced myself yet) to be executing concurrently.

Comment: `all` takes a single *array* parameter, not multiple parameters.

Comment: If you have a comment on one of the answers, use the comment section below that answer. I have added a paragraph to my answer to what seems to be your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like your arrays are nested, so you can also nest the `.all` calls.

Here with native promises, but it's the same with bluebird:

```js
const a = [Promise.resolve('a'), Promise.resolve('b'), Promise.resolve('c')]; 
const b = [Promise.resolve('d'), Promise.resolve('e'), Promise.resolve('f')]; 
const c = [Promise.resolve('g'), Promise.resolve('h'), Promise.resolve('i')]; 

Promise.all([a, b, c].map(x => Promise.all(x))).then(responses => {
    console.log(responses); // [["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"],["g","h","i"]]
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

All promises will be created immediately, and the final promise will resolve when the last original promise resolves. Here is a variant of the above snippet that illustrates that:

```js
const delayed = (ms, val) => new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(_ => resolve(val), ms) );

var a = [delayed( 500, 'a'), delayed( 700, 'b'), delayed( 300, 'c')]; 
var b = [delayed( 200, 'd'), delayed(1000, 'e'), delayed( 800, 'f')]; 
var c = [delayed( 600, 'g'), delayed( 900, 'h'), delayed( 400, 'i')]; 

Promise.all([a, b, c].map(x => Promise.all(x))).then(responses => {
    console.log(responses); // [["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"],["g","h","i"]]
});

setTimeout(_ => console.log('all should be resolved'), 1050);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) or [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to create a new array.

The concat version would look like this:

`Bluebird.all(a.concat(b).concat(c))`

And the spread version:

`Bluebird.all([...a, ...b, ...c])`